# APN SSL Certificate valid period

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

We have deployed our application with push notifications using a development provision profile. The APNS SSL certificate expires from 3 months , so my client wants to extend it's valid period preferably by several years. Is it possible to get a 3rd Party SSL certificate to connect to APNS ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You must generate the certificate through the iOS Provisioning Profile. By the way, you need to deploy your application using a production certificate and not a development certificate.

Comment: Adding to what Dylan said, the production cert has a longer expiration period (1 year).